# making spinner treat as simple button

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to click my spinner and take actions just as similar taken by clicking any button , but a dialog is always shown onspinner click, my code is:

```
 final View.OnTouchListener sp = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch1(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                list(); //function to call
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            list();   /function to call

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: i don't understand what you want. do you want a view that only looks like a spinner, but does something completely different? then why can't use just use a different view?

Comment: You can also make a button look like a spinner...

Comment: This is a bad approach, IMHO, unless you have an extremely good reason. If the user sees something that looks like a `Spinner` then they will expect options and think something is wrong if it just does stuff they aren't expecting.

Comment: @codeMagic I beg to differ slightly, take the google calendar app for example, they use this approach and show a dialog instead of a dropdown. Its also the same with the `QuickContactBadge`; that also has the arrow like a spinner but does not act like a spinner. I think as long as you are showing some sort of popup it is ok

Comment: @tyczj I'm not sure which part of the Google calendar app you are talking about but showing a dialog is still showing options and is a view associated with `Spinner`. It doesn't have to be a drop down but I am saying if it doesn't show some type of options screen. I don't know what the OP's `list()` function does so I can't say for sure. I'm just saying to be careful when you get away from what a user expects

Comment: @codeMagic when you go to create a new event they have `TextViews` with the spinner style and show a `DatePicker` when pressed

Comment: @tyczj Mine looks like `Button`s but still it is what I am expecting to do. And as I said a popout dialog is still something that a user can expect. It doesn't have to be a dropdown. Anyway, that's just my opinion. I am just saying to be careful and make sure its something the users expect to see

Answer (score 2):

spinners dont have the ability to do what you want.

what you can do however is create a `textview/button` with a spinner style so that it looks like a spinner using

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

then just put an `onClick` listener to that textview and do whatever you want on the click